# Cachegring file very small

Tags: profiling, xdebug, kcachegrind

I am new to profiling.  I am trying to profile my PHP with xdebug.

The cachegrind file is created but has no significant content

I have set xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind+%p+%H+%R.cg

I call my page with additional GET parameter ?XDEBUG_PROFILE=1
My cachegrind file is generated but has no significant content

Here is my output:

```
version: 1
creator: xdebug 2.7.0alpha1 (PHP 7.0.30-dev)
cmd: C:\WPNserver\www\DMResources\Classes\VendorClasses\PHPMySQLiDatabase\MysqliDb.php
part: 1
positions: line

events: Time Memory

fl=(1)
fn=(221) php::mysqli->close
1244 103 -14832

fl=(42)
fn=(222) MysqliDbExt->__destruct
1239 56 0
cfl=(1)
cfn=(221)
calls=1 0 0
1244 103 -14832
```

That's it - I must be missing something fundamental.

Answer (score 0):

I think you hit [this bug](https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1669) in xdebug.
As suggested by Derick in the issue tracker, you can workaround this by adding %r to the profiler output name. eg: xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind+%p+%H+%R+%r.cg
(with %r adding a random number to the name)